# gstreamer: Demux & Remux MKV, preserving video

Tags: gstreamer, video-processing, gstreamer-1.0, mkv

I am trying to reencode the audio part of a  MKV file that contains some `video/x-h264` and some `audio/x-raw`.  I can't manage to just demux the MKV and remux it.  Even simply:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mkv ! matroskademux name=demux \
    matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test2.mkv \
    demux.video_00 ! mux.video_00 \
    demux.audio_00 ! mux.audio_00
```

fails miserably with:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:demux: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/gst/parse/grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:demux:
failed delayed linking pad  video_00 of GstMatroskaDemux named demux to pad  video_00 of GstMatroskaMux named mux
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:demux: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
../gstreamer/gst/parse/grammar.y(506): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:demux:
failed delayed linking pad  audio_00 of GstMatroskaDemux named demux to pad  audio_00 of GstMatroskaMux named mux
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:demux: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst-plugins-good/gst/matroska/matroska-demux.c(5715): gst_matroska_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatroskaDemux:demux:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

My best attempt at the transcoding mentioned above goes:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=test.mkv ! matroskademux name=demux \
   matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test2.mkv \
   demux.video_00 ! queue ! 'video/x-h264' ! h264parse ! mux. \
   demux.audio_00 ! queue ! rawaudioparse ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! mux.
```

with the same result.  Removing the pad name `audio_00` leads to `gst` being stuck at `PREROLLING`.

I have seen a few people facing similar problems:

- http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Putting-h264-file-inside-a-container-td4668158.html
- http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Changing-the-container-format-td3576914.html

As therein, keeping only video or only audio works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `rawaudioparse` should not be here. I tried your pipeline and trouble with it too. I just came up with something as I would have done it and it seemed to work:

```
filesrc location=test.mkv ! matroskademux \
  matroskademux0. ! queue ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test2.mkv \
  matroskademux0. ! queue ! h264parse ! matroskamux0.
```

Audio in my case was:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_f32le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, flt, 2822 kb/s (default)
```

Another format may require addiitonal transformations..

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, Florian.  Your example works indeed!  And trying to make it converge to my pipeline, I realized that `rawaudioparse` is not to be blamed.  The actual problem was *to use `video_00` instead of `video_0`*, and likewise for `audio`.  Now the documentation does use `video_00`, but it seems that the format change at some point, but the documentation was entirely updated…  Basically, removing the pads in my command above provides a working command.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pads `video_00` and `audio_00` have been renamed `video_0` and `audio_0`.  This can be seen using `gst-inspect-1.0 matroskademux`, which indicates that the format for the pads now reads `video_%u`.  *Note that some documentation pages of gstreamer are not updated to reflect that.*

The first command, MKV to MKV should read:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mkv ! matroskademux name=demux \
    matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test2.mkv \
    demux.video_0 ! queue ! mux.video_0 \
    demux.audio_0 ! queue ! mux.audio_0
```

(Note the added `queue`s)

The second command, MKV to MKV reencoding audio should read:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=test.mkv ! matroskademux name=demux \
   matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=test2.mkv \
   demux.video_0 ! queue ! 'video/x-h264' ! h264parse ! mux. \
   demux.audio_0 ! queue ! rawaudioparse ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! mux.
```

The same result could have been achieved by *not specifying the pads* and using cap filters if needed.

*Thanks go to user Florian Zwoch for providing a working pipeline.*